# Finding the smallest binary relation in a given set including a relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

The following binary relation of the set {a, b, c, d, e} is given:

R = { (a,b), (a,c), (b,c) }

What I have to do is to find the smallest reflexive / symmetric / transitive / antisymmetric relation including R.

I know what these relations are all about, but what I have trouble with is how to find them. For example, I see no reflexive relation in the set. Does "including R" mean that i can extend R with any element from the given set? So for example, if I am looking for a reflexion can I just add (a, a)?

If I can extend the set, my solution would be:

```
Reflexive: Add (a,a)
Symmetric: Add (b,a)
Transitive: Already satisfied
Antisymmetric: Already satisfied? I am not sure about this one
```

Comment: Are you sure you want symmetric and anti-symmetric?

Comment: @AdamHughes Yes

Comment: Then that's impossible. Symmetric would require $(b,a)\in R'$ since $(a,b)\in R$. Then by anti-symmetry this would have to imply $a=b$ which is false.

Comment: Perhaps, for each property (individually), you need to extend the relation, including R, in order to satisfy the property in question.

Comment: @AdamHughes oh sorry, not a relation including all of them, but a separate one for each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. "Containing" means just what you would think, since $R$ is a set, we want another set of pairs of elements $(x,y)\in S\times S$ so that $R\subseteq R'$ and $R'$ has one of the properties you mention.

First you need to add $(x,x)$ for every $x\in S=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ which will give you $R_r=R\cup\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c), (d,d), (e,e)\}$--the smallest **reflexive** relation containing $R$.

For a **symmetric** one, you need to add all of the elements of $R$ where you switch $x$ and $y$, i.e. $R_s=R\cup\{(b,a), (c,a), (c,b)\}$

Continuing for the others, we need a **transitive** one, so we need to see if there are $xRy$ and $yRz$, and in-fact there is exactly one, namely since $aRb$ and $bRc$ we need to add $aRc$, but you already have $(a,c)\in R$, so $R_t=R$.

Finally **anti-symmetry** is already satisfied, since there are no $x,y\in S$ such that $xRy$ and $yRx$, so $R=R_a$ is already anti-symmetric. If you have trouble seeing how this is, remember that antisymmetric is parsed in logical symbols as

$$\forall x,y\in S (xRy\land yRx\implies x=y)$$

Since the set of $x,y\in S$ such that $xRy$ and $yRx$ is empty, the condition is vacuously true because all $\forall z\in\varnothing$ statements are vacuously true because the negation is $\exists z'\in\varnothing$ which is clearly false, since there are no elements in an empty set.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Can you explain why for example for reflexive I have to add all those tuples including (e,e) even when e was not even part of R.

Comment: Because reflexive means that **all** elements are related to themselves. So you need all elements from the initial set.

Comment: I understand, but why is this not the case for the transitive and symmetric relation? When I check the definitions reflexive is aRa and symmetric is aRb -> bRa. (a, b elements of A, Relation is R).

Comment: Symmetric and transitive have hypotheses, reflexive just says for all

Comment: Is that an universal definition? I sometimes had the problem that mathematicians around the world define things differently. E.g. in my lecture R ° S starts with S, but for others that it starts with R.

Comment: Reflexive relations are always ones in which all $(x,x)\in S\times S$ are in the relation, yes.

Comment: I've got another question, based on your answers. Let's say I have an R that forms a cycle. Do I still have to make sure all elements are connected - or is that automatically achieved by the cycle?

Comment: @xxsl what do you mean "$R$ that forms a cycle"? What is a cycle? $R$ is just a set of ordered pairs. Reflexive relations--by definition--include **all** ordered pairs of the form $(x,x)$ with $x\in S$. And I don't know what you mean by "do I have to make sure[...]" that depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I transformed that into a separate question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020736/symmetric-relations-and-cycles