# Symmetric Relations and Cycles

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let's say I have the set:

R = {(a,b),(b,c),(c,d),(d,a)}

If you visualize this in graph form, it forms a cycle.

My question is, is this already a symmetric relation, or do I have to add (b,a),(b,c),(d,c),(d,a) to make it symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symmetric **requires** that $(x,y)\in R\implies (y,x)\in R$, your relation does not have that. Remember that the different relation properties such as reflexive, transitive, et cetera are not implied by one another, they are all independent.

In order that your relation be symmetric you need to check that it satisfies the definition as noted above. Since you lack, for example, $(b,a)$, it fails to satisfy the definition of a symmetric relation.

Comment: Transitive? $(a,c),(b,d),(c,a),(d,b)\notin R$.

Comment: You're right, of course, @AsafKaragila. I migrated here from another recent question from the op, and had the wrong context in mind. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. I don't know why I have such a hard time understanding this field of discrete mathematics. I've been programming for a few years now and I have no problem with logic or algebra, but things like this, something which I can't prove give me headaches.

Comment: @xxsl the trick is usually just to check the definitions. It's not meant to be heavily tricky, with lots of crazy out-of-left-field ideas. It's just read the definitions, see if your set works with them. If yes, done! If not, it doesn't have the property.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, if the relation is "symmetric" and contains $(a,b)$ it *must* also contain $(b,a)$.

There's nothing particularly deep about that; it is just how the word "symmetric" happens to be used about relations.

As you (almost) point out, the relation has *other* symmetries than the one represented by looking at it backwards -- for example the relation is preserved by certain permutations of its underlying set. This would usually be called a "symmetry" of it, except that there's a strong convention that when we speak about relations, "symmetry" is reserved for speaking about the correspondence $(a,b)\leftrightarrow(b,a)$.